# Dynamic sidebar based on category

Tags: widgets, sidebar

I am new to wordpress, i have developed a basic theme to make a tutorial web site, for that i need a dynamic sidebar based on category,

suppose, i have category A & B, if user is on the A category i need to display A sidebar, if it's in B category need to display B sidebar,

The sidebar will hold the menu items.

for Demo website see: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/, click on the any manu and see the sidebar.

i have searched plugin to achieve the stuff, but can't find it. if there is any plugin please suggest,

Comment: Hi Olive, plugin recommendations are off-topic http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many solutions to your problem, I guess. Two solutions I would recommend are:

### 1. Register multiple sidebars.

Register more sidebars and then include them conditionally in page templates. So if you need different sidebar for each category (let's say you have 2 categories), then register 2 more sidebars (sidebar-cat-1, sidebar-cat-2) and then replace generic sidebar with one of these two, based on what category is displayed.

### 2. There is plugin for that ;)

You could check these plugins:

- http://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-logic/
- http://wordpress.org/plugins/conditional-widgets/

Comment: You are awesome!! both the plugins are what i want, need to learn condition for widget-logic plugin, but i like the conditional widget.
Thanks for the answer!

Comment: This link should help you with conditions: http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags